# ExceptionPolicy vs ExceptionManager

Tags: .net, exception, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, application-blocks

What is the difference between *exceptionpolicy* and *exceptionmanager* classes of Microsoft Enterprise Library?? I didn't even know that *exceptionmanager* existed! Why are there two different classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ExceptionManager Exists**

[See this Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solutions.btarn.shared.exceptionmanager%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx)

I'll prefer ExceptionManger to handle my all exception as i can compare exception, start process according to exception policy, can know the type of exception
while ExceptionPolicy just give me a single member function to handle exception nothing else...

you should also go through from these links...

[1. Members of ExceptionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.exceptionhandling.exceptionmanager_members.aspx)

[2. Members of ExceptionPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.exceptionhandling.exceptionpolicy_members.aspx)

[3. Introduction to the Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649923.aspx#intro_polocoes)